# How to install MySQL on Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu

I want to install the latest version of MySQL on my Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS desktop, then try to use it as a local database, but I have been confused because there are a lot of different files here:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I don't know which file(s) are needed to be downloaded?

Also the same issue here for the MySQL Workbench:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

There are two different files for downloading for Ubuntu 22.04!

Comment: Why not following [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-linux/)  or [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04)?

Comment: @ErgestBasha: I wanted to learn how to install the latest version?

Comment: The latest version will be installed. You could download [mysql-server_8.0.31-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (*Select Operating System: Ubuntu Linux ,Select OS Version: Ubuntu Linux 22.04*) and install it with `dpkg -i mysql-server_8.0.31-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb` but you have to follow an order during install if I'm not mistaken (it's been a while since I last installed from .deb).

Comment: @ErgestBasha: Thank you! Do you know for the `Worckbench` wich file should I download? There are a 30MB and a 60MB file when I search for it in the second link I put in my question. Also when I try to install it using `sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community` it gives me the following error: `E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community`

Comment: `(mysql-workbench-community_8.0.31-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb)` I guess, i never use MySQL workbench. Follow this tutorial https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-workbench-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the descriptions of the packages/bundles/debs some have this string: "dbgsym" those are installs with debugging symbols installed. Probably you do not want those (if you did want them, you would know)
On your Worksapce Question: the 60M field are debug symbols.

As Ergest said above that package is the APT configuration, (its 65K) once that is complete two more commands:  sudo apt update && sudo apt install